# Greenplum-Spark-Connector java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: apache-spark, greenplum

My work Envorinments like bellow:
. Hadoop 2.7.2
. Spark 2.3.0
. Greenplum 6.8.1  <- I knew this version is latest.

and I have to create dataframe(RDD) from GPDB table. so, I have knew a "Greenplum-spark-connector". An architecture sounds good. but It does not work.

I tried like this:

```
spark/bin$spark-shell 
--master spark://10.40.203.99:7077 
--jars /data2/install_files/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.2.jar,/data2/install_files/postgresql-42.2.5.jar,/data2/install_files/jetty-io-9.2.26.v20180806.jar,/data2/install_files/jetty-server-9.2.26.v20180806.jar,/data2/install_files/jetty-util-9.2.26.v20180806.jar 
--driver-class-path /data2/install_files/postgresql-42.2.5.jar



spark-shell
scala> scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val ddf = spark.read.format("greenplum")
.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://{GPDB_MASTER_IP}/{DATABASE_NAME}")
.option("server.port","12900")
.option("dbtable", "airports")
.option("dbschema","test")
.option("user", "user")
.option("password", "passw0rd!")
.option("partitionColumn","airportid")
.option("partitions",1)
.load()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

2020-07-01 01:55:20 WARN  ObjectStore:6666 - Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.2.0
2020-07-01 01:55:20 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database default, returning NoSuchObjectException
2020-07-01 01:55:21 WARN  ObjectStore:568 - Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
ddf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [airportid: int, name: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> ddf.show()
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]2020-07-01 01:55:33 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.40.203.99, executor 0): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
        at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.getDistributedTransactionId(Jdbc.scala:500)
        at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:100)
        at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2020-07-01 01:55:33 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.40.203.99, executor 0): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
        at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
        at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.getDistributedTransactionId(Jdbc.scala:500)
        at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:100)
        at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3253)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3252)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2484)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2698)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:723)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:682)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:691)
  ... 49 elided
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
  at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.getDistributedTransactionId(Jdbc.scala:500)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:100)
  at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**It occurs "No Such element Exception".  So, I try to check *.jar-dependency. but I can get any Build-information via pom.xml.
How can I start to check this code...**

Answer (score 1):

The Greenplum Spark Connector version 1.6.2 is incompatible with Greenplum versions 6.7.1+. Currently we don't offer a connector for those versions of Greenplum. We'll be releasing a new Greenplum Spark Connector that supports all versions of Greenplum in the near future.

Comment: I checked this connector supports greenplum version 6.x on this Docs
(https://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/1-6/GSC160ReleaseNotes.html).

Is that wrong? you mean...the connector(1.6.2) supports under greemplum-6.7.1.. right?

Comment: Documentation has been updated to reflect this. Version 1.7.0 of the connector has been released and fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. frankgh. I checked that news and tested it. it works well. and it had high speed loading gp-data in spark-memoory.       and Was there some bug in 1.6.2 connector?

Comment: @coolsk there was an issue in 1.6.2 that has been addressed in 1.7.0. Can you mark this as the accepted answer and upvote if you are satisfied with the solution? thanks