# java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get Error in show() operation of Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, greenplum

I tried to retrieve data from Greenplum database and show it using Pyspark.This is the code that I have implemented.

```
import pyspark

from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("spkapp") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "100")\
        .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")\
        .config("spark.network.timeout", "600s")\
        .config('spark.executor.cores','1')\
        .getOrCreate()

gscPythonOptions = {
    "url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name",
    "user": "my_user",
    "password": "",
    "dbschema": "public"

}

gpdf_swt = spark.read.format("greenplum").options(**gscPythonOptions,dbtable="products",partitionColumn= "id").load()

gpdf_swt.printSchema()

gpdf_swt.show()
```

But when I run my python file using spark submit it gives me an error like below.

```
20/12/30 21:23:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/credit_card/summary_table_creation2Test.py", line 38, in <module>
    gpdf_swt.count()
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 524, in show
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o84.show.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.jdbc.Jdbc$.getDistributedTransactionId(Jdbc.scala:500)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.externaltable.GreenplumRowIterator.<init>(GreenplumRowIterator.scala:100)
    at io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRDD.compute(GreenplumRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my spark-submit command.

```
/usr/local/spark/bin/spark-submit --driver-class-path /root/greenplum/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.2.jar summary_table_creation
```

Any help is appreciated to overcome from this error.

Edit -:
My Greenplum version is 6.4.0. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662826/greenplum-spark-connector-java-util-nosuchelementexception-none-get). But its solution is applicable only for the greenplum versions that are higher than 6.7.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Greenplum-Spark-Connector java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662826/greenplum-spark-connector-java-util-nosuchelementexception-none-get)

Comment: My greenplum version is 6.4.0. But on the above post it mentioned that the the problem only occurred for the versions higher than 6.7.1.

Comment: @Harini what version of the spark connector are you using?

Comment: @frankgh I tried both the versions 1.6.2 and 1.7.0

Comment: The Greenplum user (i.e., `my_user`) needs to have `SELECT` privileges on the `pg_settings` and `gp_distributed_xacts` catalog tables. I suspect that your user doesn't and that is causing a PSQL exception which is being thrown away//turned in to a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: If you can search your GPDB log file ($MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY/pg_log/*.csv) for any errors around the string pg_settings, that would be helpful.